# Adding mouse event handler to menu in javafx

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am new to javafx and is currently working on menu, menuitems. I wish to override the default event of displaying contextMenu, which is currently shown even if menu is not pressed but mouse is hovered over it while neighbouring menu's contextMenu is shown. This happens in every application, since its very handy. But for some reason I do not need it. I tried capturing the mouse event on menu,so that I can work accordingly, but nothing happens.

```
menu.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse event occured");
            });
```

here `menu` is the one to which I want to add this behaviour.

Comment: where did you add this code? in fxml controller or in application class?

Comment: it is added in controller associated with menubar fxml

Comment: actually you can not add a mouse handler to the menu like this. try to use simple menu and menu item if you do not want hover action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that one cannot add mouse-event to menu in javafx directly, but there's a workaround that I managed to figure out. Now the workaround involves menuBar (on which menu is placed), which can capture the mouse-event. So adding a eventFilter on menuBar for mouse-event,

```
    // variable to store the mouse-event-type 
       private MouseEvent mouseEventType

    // for registering mouse pressed event;
    // addEventFilter since it is called during the capturing phase
      mainMenu.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, mouseEvent -> {
      mouseEventType = mouseEvent;
    });
```

and then handling the event in menu.setOnShown does the trick.

```
   // handle the mouse-event like this
      menu.setOnShown( event -> {
             if(mouseEventType.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)){
                 //TODO something
             }else{
                 //TODO something 
             }
            });
```

So what happens here is that, mouseEventType is initialized to `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` on click on the menu, and instantly the setOnShown is invoked with default action of showing `contextMenu` containing the menuItems. Now accordingly different logic can be given.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the listener to the `styleableNode` of `MenuItem` (`getStyleableNode().addEventFilter(...`).

This property is `null` initially, in my case I just add the listener on `show()` (add it once only / remove it as needed).